# JS - Adding an active class to an element with the same data attribute as the hovered element

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to achieve a similar effect as on [this page](https://www.zendesk.com/) section "Something for everyone". After hovering over any of the "link" elements, the "product" element with the same "data-product" value should get the "active" class. I need to achive it in pure JS (without jQuery). I did several approaches but never successful. Do you know any examples that could help me?

```
<div class="product-links">
    <a class="link" data-product="1" href="/url/"></a>
    <a class="link" data-product="2" href="/url/"></a>
    <a class="link" data-product="3" href="/url/"></a>
    <a class="link" data-product="4" href="/url/"></a>
</div>

<div class="screenshot-container">
    <div class="product" data-product="1"><img src="image.jgp"></div>
    <div class="product" data-product="2"><img src="image.jgp"></div>
    <div class="product" data-product="3"><img src="image.jgp"></div>
    <div class="product" data-product="4"><img src="image.jgp"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential approach that uses the `mouseover` event and some event bubbling to add the `active` class to whichever link is currently being hovered over.

```js
const linkContainer = document.querySelector(".product-links");

linkContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className !== "link") return;
  const productId = e.target.dataset.product;
  selectActive(productId);
});

linkContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className !== "link") return;
  selectActive();
});

function selectActive(productId) {
  const allProducts = document.querySelectorAll(".product");
  for (let product of allProducts) {
    if (product.dataset.product === productId) {
      product.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      product.classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-links">
    <a class="link" data-product="1" href="/url/">1</a>
    <a class="link" data-product="2" href="/url/">2</a>
    <a class="link" data-product="3" href="/url/">3</a>
    <a class="link" data-product="4" href="/url/">4</a>
</div>

<div class="screenshot-container">
    <div class="product" data-product="1">1</div>
    <div class="product" data-product="2">2</div>
    <div class="product" data-product="3">3</div>
    <div class="product" data-product="4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `e.target.getAttribute("data-product")` can be simplified to `e.target.dataset.product`. Also consider using `product.classList.toggle('active', e.target.dataset.product === productId)` instead of `if/else` in `selectActive`.